# Flexslider buga em Tab ou Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

Estou fazendo uma tab com 1 Flexslider ( Slider ) em cada tab, porém o primeiro funciona tranquilamente, já a segunda TAB o slider buga, ou seja, eu tenho que ou minimizar o navegador ou abrir inspetor de elemento.

Procurei algumas coisas e achei que o Jquery não trabalha com elementos ocultos.

Se alguém souber resolver o problema fico grato.
Por favor me avisarem se ficou mal entendido.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é apenas o modo de renderizar a Tela.

O Jquery trabalha com a árvore DOM ativa, o que é gerando após o Load inicial da página deve se chamar novamente o Função do Flexslider, para que o Jquery reconheça os novos elementos DOM;

Comment: Mesmo iniciando quando clico na aba, ele não funciona, fica bugado do mesmo jeito. Coloquei alguns timeouts e mesmo assim continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: Por favor cria um Codepen?